# Complex Scalar Field Differential Forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

over the last week i have been trying to learn differential forms to try and tackle a problem, I believe I understand it, but I'm not quite sure, here is the problem:

Given a complex scalar field $\phi(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ defined on $\mathbb{R^3}$ which is well defined as $r\rightarrow \infty$, and $r=\sqrt{x_1^2 +x_2^2 +x_3^2}$
$\phi$ can be identified as $\phi : S^3 \rightarrow S^2$  $S^3 \equiv R^3 \cup \{\infty\}$ and $S^2 \equiv C^1 \cup \{\infty\}$ i.e the hopf map

the area two form is given by $F = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\frac{d\phi*\wedge d\phi}{(1+\phi*\phi)^2}$

is this expansion correct: $F =\frac{1}{2\pi i}(\frac{\partial \phi* }{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial \phi }{\partial x_j}-\frac{\partial \phi* }{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial \phi }{\partial x_i})(\frac{1}{(1+\phi*\phi)^2} ) dx_i \wedge dx_j  $
 where i $\neq$ j and x, j = 1, 2, 3

is $\phi$ considered as a 0-form?
$d\phi$ a 1-form in dual space $dx_i$?
and F an area in dual space (2-form)?

Thanks!

Comment: no, because the 1st term is not a 2-form

Comment: @janmarqz are you saying F is not a two form? or the expansion i gave?

Comment: you already fixed, right?

Comment: @janmarqz I fixed the brackets, i didnt want to make it one fraction as it would be tiny. Is this all correct now?

Comment: how do you define explicitly $\phi$, $\phi*$, $d\phi$ and $d\phi*$?

Comment: @janmarqz this is from a physics paper and is all it has to say on the matter. http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/25/6/020/pdf , not sure if thats pay walled.